# rails3.1.1 and sunspot: Solr Response: Not Found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm trying to build an application with sunspot_solr and I keep getting this error:

```
rsolr (0.12.1) lib/rsolr/connection/requestable.rb:39:in `request'
rsolr (0.12.1) lib/rsolr/client.rb:34:in `request'
sunspot (1.2.1) lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:35:in `execute'
sunspot_rails (1.2.1) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:306:in `solr_execute_search'
sunspot_rails (1.2.1) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:139:in `solr_search'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:7:in `results'
```

Here is my sunspot.yml:

```
solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8980
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr
    pid_dir: /solr/pids/development
    auto_commit_after_delete_request: true
```

And the solr instance at http://localhost:8980/solr/admin/ does work, I get all the desired results when I run the queries there. But when I run through my application I get the above error.

My configuration:
Rails 3.1.1
Sunspot: 1.2.1

Please let me know what other information you need from me and thanks in advance for the answers.

I went through the logs files and found out this error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <class:User> at /home/romio/hummingtown_v1/app/models/user.rb:17)
```

Here is my user.rb:

```
require 'digest/sha2'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :userauths, :dependent => :destroy

    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :salt

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :with => email_regex }, 
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
        text :first_name, :default_boost => 2
        text :last_name
        text :email
    end
```

Comment: It worked after I upgraded my sunspot to 1.3.0 and rsolr to 1.0.6